# using matplotlib in blender causes import error when trying to import distutils

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, blender

I'm trying to import matplotlib.delaunay from blender python console. It fails on the following callstack:

```
>>> import matplotlib.delaunay
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.73\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    import distutils.version
ImportError: No module named 'distutils'
```

For some reason when I do that in my WinPython environment it works perfectly. Now distutils is located in numpy, which is identical in my WinPython and Blender environments, just in WinPython is somehow manages to import distutils, while it doesn't in Blender environment. Matplotlib and numpy are identical in both environments. I'm obviously missing something, question is what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Silly me, I was looking for it in lib/site-packages when I should have in lib/

Please close this one.

Comment: Can you import matplotlib.pyplot?